# How alter List<int> with LINQ ForEach

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have a `List<int> myInts` and want to multiply all with 10. I want to use linq (not foreach loop).I tryed this but nothing happend:

```
List<int> myInts = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
myInts .ForEach(act => act=act*10);
```

Of what do I have to take care in the `.ForEach(...)` part? And yes, I want to use ForEach if it is somehow possible.

Probably its simple, but I cant see it, I apoligize. Thank you all!

Comment: Reassigning to the local variable (`act`) has *no effect* in the caller (`ForEach`) because C# is [Call By Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) (except for ref/out parameters).

Answer (score 5):

This creates a new instance of List.

```
myInts = myInts.Select(p=>p*10).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

"Nothing happens" because reassigning to the local variable (`act`) has *no effect* in the caller (`ForEach`) - C# is [Call By Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) (except for ref/out parameters).

To modify the list *in place*, simply use a standard for-each over the indices (which I find readable and upfront of the side-effect intent):

```
var myInts = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
for (var i = 0; i < myInts.Count; i++) {
    myInts[i] = myInts[i] * 10;
}
```

To perform the operation and create a new list/sequence (which can be re-assigned to the same variable), see [`IEnumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is a [map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29) transformation.

Answer (score 3):

Another and simpler solution:

```
list = list.ConvertAll(i => i * 10);
```

Comment: @Johnny not working? I tried, and it worked perfectly. Which .net framework version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, while testing I had a spelling mistake. It is Working! :)

Comment: what side effects are you relating to?

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN documentation:

```
Modifying the underlying collection in the body of the Action<T> delegate 
is not supported and causes undefined behavior.
```

So, you need to project your exisistin List into a new one, or you need to use a for loop if you must modify the List "in place"

Regards

Comment: The documentation you cite has nothing to do with the question. The warning refers to modification of the structure of the collection, i.e. removal or insertion/addition of elements, not simple replacement of values.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that you are getting a value copy of the int to your the lambda, which so you won't be able to change the 'external' int.

How about projecting a new list?

```
List<int> myInts = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
myInts = myInts.Select(act => act*10).ToList();
```

Comment: There is a slight error in your projection, the correct statement would be `myInts.Select(act => act*10).ToList();`

Answer (score 1):

To use a `.Select` or [`.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are good solutions.

But my intention was to let "`ForEach`" return an alterd list.
I found out, over msdn documentation, that this isn´t possible because ForEach is a `void` type and has no returntype.

This kind of action works if I would have objects in my List instead of ints. Then I would be able to use the "void" Method to change the properties of my objects.

Comment: As "ojlovecd" showed you can convert the list and then imagine:
 ... 

 myStrings = myInts.ConvertAll(o => (o * 10).ToString() + " text");

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this ?

```
     List<int> _tempList = new List<int>();
     myInts.ToList().ForEach(x => _tempList.Add(x * 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, myInts.Count).ToList().ForEach(i => myInts[i] = myInts[i] * 10);
```